# .bind is not working with dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below .bind event - I can not reproduce the result - when I am injecting a dynamic html.
Tried with .on/.live but those are not working

```
function initToggleDetails() {
    abc.Log("initToggleaction");

    $('.alink').unbind('click.link');

    $('.alink').bind('click.link', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        togglelDetailsaction(this);
    });
```

Comment: How do you trigger the event?

Comment: @VisioN: Namespaced events. http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, that makes sense. I totally forgot about this option.

Comment: You can't reproduce the result? Great, so the bug has disappeared? @VisioN You shouldn't delete a comment from a conversation, that renders it incomprehensible.

Comment: This will be difficult to help with if you cannot reproduce the result.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the delegated version of on() / off() ???

```
$(document).off('click.link', '.alink');

$(document).on('click.link', '.alink', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    togglelDetails(this);
});
```